# mod_rewrite to zeus rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, zeus

Can the server I am working on for a client only runs zeus rewrite rules and the CMS I am using requires the following code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Is there a way to rename that so that it will work with zeus?

Comment: where you able to find the answer yourself? I was looking for a same solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for:

http://drupal.org/node/46508

Make sure you read to the end where a modified version of the script is with info about which file to post it in if you don't have access to the zeus admin.